# Use saturating_add if available in Rust, fallback to regular addition for floats

Tags: generics, rust, traits

I am trying to write a function that is defined for *both* floats and integers.

For integers, I want to use [`saturating_add`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.u32.html#method.saturating_add).
For floats, there is no saturating_add function, but regular add is saturating (in the sense that infinity_value + positive_value = infinity_value).

What I would *like* to write is

```rust
fn sat_add<T: num_traits::Num>(x: T, o: T) -> T {
  if implements(x, num_traits::ops::saturating::SaturatingAdd)
    x.saturating_add(o) // Saturating addition, if available
  else
    x + o // Fallback: regular addition
}
```

Note that T is static, and I want this to be inlined by the compiler. So its more of a pattern matching (trait present or not) rather than object-oriented programming.

(Note that I am currently using macros to implement either one or the other for various standard types, but that only covers the basic cases, something generic would be nicer than enumerating known data types.)

Answer (score 3):

You can define a trait and implement it for the desired types:

```rust
pub trait MyAdd {
    fn my_add(self, o: Self) -> Self;
}
macro_rules! my_add_int {
    ($($t:ty),+) => {$(
        impl MyAdd for $t {
            fn my_add(self, o:Self) -> Self {
                <$t>::saturating_add(self, o)
            }
        }
    )*}
}
macro_rules! my_add_float {
    ($($t:ty),+) => {$(
        impl MyAdd for $t {
            fn my_add(self, o:Self) -> Self {
                self + o
            }
        }
    )*}
}
my_add_int!(i8, u8, i16, u16, i32, u32, i64, u64, isize, usize);
my_add_float!(f32, f64);
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=3c83f3300dfa4ccc1d9bee4e885b9cc0)

Comment: Can the repeated use of the macro be simplified by just implementing it for [`num::PrimInt`](https://docs.rs/num/0.4.0/num/trait.PrimInt.html)? Or even more direct, directly tying it to [`num::traits::SaturatingAdd`](https://docs.rs/num/0.4.0/num/traits/trait.SaturatingAdd.html)? Two uses for the only two floating point primitives is one thing, but it's a pain to have to manually attach to 10 types.

Comment: @ShadowRanger what about now ? I think it's preferable not to import a crate just to gain a dozen characters in the source. And the number of integer types isn't expected to change much.

Comment: Heh. That's nicer. :-) I just find if I'm going to write code like this anyway, I'd depend on `num` for a bunch of little things anyway, so why not make use of its traits? (also, I'm terrified of Rust macros, but that's a personal failing)

Comment: I meet a compiler warning "function cannot return without recursing" when I `impl` the custom trait with `fn saturating_add(self, o:Self) -> Self { self.saturating_add(o) }`, is it better to use a different method name like `custom_saturating_add` as `saturating_add` is defined by `std` already?

Comment: @rustyhu For sure it would be better to use a different name. Especially as it's not even saturating for floats.

Comment: Or `$t::saturating_add` should disambiguate between your trait method and the `std` one.

Comment: @Jmb Right. I'll edit, even if I think it's better to have a different name

Comment: I don't think implementing it for x numerical types is the best way, just to have the next one using some custom complex number type, for example, or needs i128 or f128. I'd certainly prefer to implement it for traits, but it seems you can't implement a trait for multiple traits (e.g., PrimInt and Float) because someone might implement PrimInt + Float and then it would be ambiguous, and there is no "PrimInt -Float" and "Float -PrimInt" that would be disjoint.

Comment: @ErichSchubert In practice, open automatic implementations are most often a problem when your code changes. What matters most is the ease of refactoring, rather than trying to guess the exact scope which will be needed in the future.

Comment: Well, as rust does not allow implementing traits if neither the trait nor the type are in your own module, I'm not that happy with this solution. So if you'd use a library with a high-precision numerical type or complex numbers, you can't implement MyAdd<Complex> for my library, but need to wrap it in yet another type, and probably also add some auto-conversion traits, which makes refactoring not particularly easy in the long run with nested wrappers that add no functionality.

Comment: @DenysSéguret *And the number of integer types isn't expected to change much* - I wouldn't bet on that. `u128` and `i128` were added relatively recently, well after Rust 1.0. So were the `NonZero*` types, for which saturating add would also make sense. Finally, there are always non-std types, like new and more efficient bignum/fixnum/decimal implementations. All of those can be expected to support `num_traits`, which is the de facto standard in that space.

Comment: The comments here are diving into the "XY problem" dimension. @ErichSchubert You should probably go back to the real problem you have at hand if you want a real practical solution.

Comment: Its not exactly an XY problem, because there won't ever be a type that is both float and integer.

Answer (score 1):

Doing this the way you'd like to is not possible in current Rust because it requires [specialization](https://rust-lang.github.io/rfcs/1210-impl-specialization.html).

With specialization (available on nightly), your function could be implemented like this:

```
#![feature(specialization)]

use num_traits::{ops::saturating::SaturatingAdd, Num};

// A helper trait to implement `saturating_add`
pub trait SaturatingAddHelper {
    fn add(self, rhs: Self) -> Self;
}

impl<T: Num> SaturatingAddHelper for T {
    // the fallback implementation, defined for any number
    default fn add(self: T, rhs: T) -> T {
        self + rhs
    }
}

impl<T: Num + SaturatingAdd> SaturatingAddHelper for T {
    // specialized implementation for types that define `saturating_add()`
    fn add(self: T, rhs: T) -> T {
        self.saturating_add(&rhs)
    }
}

// With the trait in place, the implementation of the function
// boils down to invoking the trait's only method.
pub fn saturating_add<T: SaturatingAddHelper>(a: T, b: T) -> T {
    a.add(b)
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=21bdf5a3bed78a542bd6417a0a67e0ed)

Unfortunately, it requires the full `specialization` feature, it doesn't work with the more modest `min_specialization`. In other words, don't expect this to become part of stable any time soon.

Comment: Thank you, this is a nicer solution that I am looking forward to see in Rust.